# Angular Material installation fail

Tags: angular, angular-material

I use the following version on my working Windows Laptop.

- Angular CLI: 9.1.15
- Node: 16.16.0
- OS: win32 x64
- Windows 10

When I add Angular Material using  **ng add @angular/material** using this command that run well.

After I let installing, It shows following error.

> The package @angular/material@16.1.5 will be installed and executed.
> Would you like to proceed? Yes
> npm WARN config global --global, --local are deprecated. Use --location=global instead.
> npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
> npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
> npm ERR! network Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/@material%2ftab-bar: abortedg/@material%2ftab-bar: aborted
> npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
> npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
> npm ERR! network
> npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
> npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
> ocal\npm-cache_logs\2023-07-27T10_40_18_833Z-deb
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\laptop\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-07-27T10_40_18_833Z-debug-0.log
> ✖ Packages installation failed, see above.

How to solve that problem?

I checked and I couldn't find solution. Specifically this is my first week with Angular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem. Thank you.

- it's very simple

run, **npm cache clear --force** on your terminal.

- Add Angular Material again